# Cocos2d NSMutable Array mutated while enumerated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, collision

I've been working on a game, and at a point I didn't have issues removing the enemy game objects (right now they are subclassed from `CCSprite` and I know that's not the best way)

But I'm not sure what I changed to make it crash when the program attempts to `removeChild` from `_targets` after they have been added to `targetsToDelete`.

I tried moving things around, I just don't know how I am adding or editing the array while its being created... Any help or advice would be great!

And actually if you had any pointers on how best to create game enemies, do you subclass `NSObject` or `CCNode`? I heard to divide them into component classes but I had no clue what they meant.

```
//Projectile Target collision

-(void)update:(ccTime)dt {

    for (spygot *target in _targets) {
        CGRect targetRect = CGRectMake(
                                       target.position.x - (target.contentSize.width/2),
                                       target.position.y - (target.contentSize.height/2),
                                       target.contentSize.width,
                                       target.contentSize.height);

        //Collision Detection Player
        CGRect playerRect2 = CGRectMake(
                                        _controlledSprite.position.x - (_controlledSprite.contentSize.width/2),
                                        _controlledSprite.position.y - (_controlledSprite.contentSize.height/2),
                                        _controlledSprite.contentSize.width,
                                        _controlledSprite.contentSize.height);

    NSMutableArray *projectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (Projectile *projectile in _projectiles) 
    {           
        NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        CGRect projectileRect = CGRectMake(
                                           projectile.position.x - (projectile.contentSize.width/2),
                                           projectile.position.y - (projectile.contentSize.height/2),
                                           projectile.contentSize.width,
                                           projectile.contentSize.height);
        BOOL monsterHit = FALSE;

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(projectileRect, targetRect))
        {
            NSLog(@"hit");
            target.mhp = target.mhp - 1;
            monsterHit = TRUE;

            if (target.mhp <= 0)
            {
                [targetsToDelete addObject:target];
            }
        }


        for (spygot *target in targetsToDelete) 
        {
            [self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];
            [_targets removeObject:target];
        }

        if (monsterHit)
        {
            [projectilesToDelete addObject:projectile];
        }

        [targetsToDelete release];
    }

    for (Projectile *projectile in projectilesToDelete) 
    {
        [_projectiles removeObject:projectile];
        [self removeChild:projectile cleanup:YES];

    }
    [projectilesToDelete release];
}
```

Comment: You wrote "crash when [attempting] to removeChild from _targets".  For the sake of clarity, do you mean that the offending line is `[self removeChild:target cleanup:YES];` or `[_targets removeObject:target];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the code that you've pasted is all from within a `for` loop iterating over `_targets`.  How does the variable `target` get initialized?

Comment: Yes I realized the crash occurs because I have a separate scheduler initiating new targets. And it always will crash when simultaneously removing a `target` from `_targets`. Good to know where the problem is occurring. But not sure how to work around it, how can I ensure they don't run simultaneously?

Comment: What is the line where the local variable `target` (which appears in the code you pasted) is initialized?

Comment: `-(void)addTarget {  
    
    spygot *target = (nil);
    target = [spygot meowgot];
    [_targets addObject:target];
    [self addChild:target z:16];}`


and this is called by 


`-(void)gameLogic:(ccTime)dt {
[self addTarget]`


which is scheduled in init


`[self schedule:@selector(gameLogic:) interval:1.0];`

Comment: So the code that you posted in your question is in your `-addTarget` method?  Could you edit your question to add the full method that the code you've posted appears in?

Comment: Okay.  Within that `-update` method, how is the local variable `target` which appears in the code you posted in your question (in, for example, this line `target.mhp = target.mhp - 1;`) initialized?  My concern is that all of the code that you posted may be wrapped in a `for (spygot *target in _targets) {/**/}` block.

Comment: yes I believe all the code is exactly that, wrapped in a for block. Does that mean it loops that process? I updated the main code posting.

Comment: Then the situation is this: you're mutating `_targets` (calling `[_targets removeObject:target]`) while `_targets` is still being enumerated (within the outer `for (spygot *target in _targets)` block).

Comment: you might try enumerating over `[ _targets copy ]` instead. (And I would use `self.targets` instead of `_targets`)

Comment: You're on the right track with `targetsToDelete`.  You need to move the line `targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` to before the `for (spygot *target in _targets)` block and move the `for (spygot *target in targetsToDelete)` block to after the `for (spygot *target in _targets)` block has completed.

Comment: Sweet.  Welcome to stackoverflow!  Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get this sort of error it's because I have the code in a block or am in some other way on a nebulous thread. How sure are you that this bit of code is not running more than once at the same time?

You could try wrapping it in the following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // do everything here.
});
```

As for advice about using CCSprite for your game enemy objects, my advice is fix it when it becomes a problem. Are you seeing issues with it right now? Premature optimization is almost as bad as doing it wrong in the first place. You'll know better at the end of the project how you should have done it earlier. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you know that you cannot remove elements from the array while you iterate over it. That is why you have `targetsToDelete` array.

But it looks to me that you do remove targets to soon.

Try this:
finish iterating the main loop and finish collecting targets to the targetsToDelete array and only after main loop is done remove the targets.